# Determine when two histogram bars diverge?

Tags: distributions

I've compiled some data on how long sleep episodes are across 4 seasons. This is easy to visualize as a probability histogram (Y is probability, X is sleep episode duration). For example, there are 450 sleep episodes in the 12-15 minute duration bin for Spring, and 350 for Autumn. It's unclear to me if I can say that there are significantly more of these episodes occurring in Spring (i.e. are these are divergent observations)?

[image: Sleep Episodes]

In other words, imagine I record your sleep and my sleep for 1 night. There are 4 times that you have a sleep episode of 12-15 minutes, and there are 6 times that I do. If this trend continues, after how many observations can I say that, with respect to the 12-15 duration bin, we sleep differently? I'm hitting a mental wall here, thanks,

Comment: This looks like a plot of a $9\times 4$ contingency table that could be evaluated using Fisher's Exact Test or even a chi-squared test to assess whether there's any significant difference in pattern at all; and then you can go on from there.  It depends on exactly which hypotheses you wish to test.

Comment: This is not clear to me, maybe you can share your data, we can have a look?

Comment: The arbitrary x-axis cutoffs involved in making histograms can lead to problems. You might be better served by modeling continuous distributions of sleep durations if you have the original duration data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Below is the updated figure, QB='sleep', and my answer follows. The ultimate question is: are the probabilities of Season X and Season Y in one particular bin different above chance levels? I decided a bootstrap method would solve this. For each bin, I recalculated the probability for both seasons 1,000 times and randomly permuted the season label, i.e., 1,000 surrogates. I then tested whether the difference between probabilities for each surrogate was greater—in magnitude and direction—against the real difference in probability (between the two seasons); the fraction for which that is true divided by 1,000 results in an alpha, or p-value. This was performed for all seasons and bins, creating 4x4 season matrices for all 9 time bins. The diagonal case (season X against itself) should always be ~1, or non-significant. The following matrix shows significance values colored from 0-0.05, black otherwise, and redundant comparisons whited-out.

[image: Seasonal Histogram]

[image: P-value matrix]

Sanity check: All diagonals are p>0.05. In the first bin (1-2 min.), where Spring and Autumn are very close in the histogram, p>0.05. In the 13-22 min. bin, Winter and Autumn are significantly different (p<<0.05) from all seasons, but Spring and Summer are not significantly different, consistent with these probabilities appearing very close in the histogram plot.

Comment: Are you answering your question? If you intend to edit the question, please do so instead of answering it, because this may mislead other users that the issue is solved.

Comment: I'm answering it.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your answer to more clearly state how this answers your question.